# Multiple background services with one ongoing notification

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am writing an app that connects to a Bluetooth device, continuously receives data from it, and stores in local db. Certain data received requires system alert to pop up. There is a main activity which just displays the status of connection and data received. It all works just fine so far, including the popups.

Since the app requires to be run in background I have implemented a "bluetooth connection" service that manages the BT connectivity, and displays ongoing notification in order to avoid being killed. For coding clarity reasons I would like separate background service to collect all data, and log it (instead of having BT service do all the work). I also prefer loose coupling between my app components, so am using GreenRobot's event bus for all IPC. As a result my BT connection service is completely unaware of any data collection/logging code - it just dispatches a message to event bus and I'd like to keep it that way.

Now I'd like to have my data collection/logging code to be run as another background service. Is there a way to ensure it runs as long as BT connection service is running? And without displaying yet another ongoing notification or tightly coupling the code between two services?

Answer (score 0):

You could let your class extend `service` so in this case you dont have to make a notification for it. Basically it keep running in the background without the need of displaying notification on the status bar. Make sure before you exit your app to `stopservice()` otherwise it will keep running until the device restarted or in somehow the user force stop your app from application manager inside of the settings.

Comment: Thats not what I asked. Obviously I am extending Service class. According to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground I should display ongoing notification reduce chances of service being killed in low memory situations. I am doing that on my BT connectivity service. The data collector service should be alive as long as BT service runs, and just implementing a regular Service does not guarantee this